# ¿como habilitar solo opciones especificas?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una pagina de practica para el registro de alumnos con los datos de semestre, paraescolar, capacitación y área propedéutica. De la cual en semestre hay 3 opciones (semestre1), (semestre3) y (semestre5).

Quiero que al seleccionar (semestre1) solo se habilite una de estas tres (paraescolar, capacitación o área propedéutica), al seleccionar (semestre3) se habiliten dos de estas (paraescolar, capacitación o área propedéutica) y al seleccionar (semestre5) se habiliten las tres.

```
  <select class="controls" id="semestre" name="semestre">
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione El Semestre -</option>
  <option value="1">Semestre 1</option>
  <option value="2">Semestre 2</option>
  <option value="3">Semestre 3</option>
</select>
    

<select class="controls" id="paraescolar" name="paraescolar" disabled>
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione El Paraescolar -</option>
  <option value="1">Educacion Fisica</option>
  <option value="2">Danza</option>
</select>

<select class="controls" id="capacitacion" name="capacitacion" disabled>
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione La Capacitacion -</option>
  <option value="1">Contabilidad</option>
  <option value="2">Informatica</option>
</select>

<select class="controls" id="propedeutica" name="propedeutica" disabled>
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione El Area Propedeutica -</option>
  <option value="1">Fisico-Matematico</option>
  <option value="2">Economico-Administrativo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A ver, ahora que veo el código, cuando dices **solo se habilite una de estas tres (paraescolar, capacitación o área propedéutica)** que significa?  Es decir, lo que me parece entender es que si yo selecciono "Semestre 1" se me habilitarán las tres, pero al seleccionar algo en cualquiera de ellas quieres que las otras dos se deshabiliten para que no puedan seleccionar más... ¿es eso?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: respondiendo a mastergurú, es que al seleccionar por ejemplo el "semestre1" al ser un nivel bajo solo me habilite una de estas (paraescolar, capacitación o área propedéutica) y así avanzando si seleccione semestre2 se me habilite dos de esas y así hasta el semestre3 que habilitaría las tres

Comment: @user301849 Sigo sin entender lo que dices.  Mírate y ejecuta la respuesta que te han dado a ver si te sirve.  Piensa que cuando dices **solo me habilite una de estas (paraescolar, capacitación o área propedéutica)** no estás diciendo **cual** de ellas quieres habilitar, y claro, si habilito "paraescolar" y resulta que no era esa la que querias en ese momento que?  O lo quieres de forma aleatoria?  Eso es lo que no se entiende (o yo no entiendo ni le veo el sentido, perdona)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para activar/desactivar dinámicamente los select puede agregar un escucha al cambio del select que se toma como valor de referencia, en este caso, el select de semestre. Basta con agregar `onchange="<nombre de la funcion>"` y en el javascript agregar la función que se encargará de esta lógica.

```js
const paraescolar = document.getElementById('paraescolar')
const capacitacion = document.getElementById('capacitacion')
const propedeutica = document.getElementById('propedeutica')

const semestre_onChange = (event) => {
  const selected = event.value;   // Valor de la opción seleccionada.
  
  // Controles que se deben habilitar/deshabilitar dinámicamente.
  const disabledControls = [ paraescolar, capacitacion, propedeutica ]
  
  // Aqui define que se tiene que activar dependiendo lo seleccionado para semestre
  const toEnable = {
    // Semestre 1
    1: [ paraescolar ],
    // Semestre 2
    2: [ paraescolar, capacitacion ],
    // Semestre 3
    3: [ paraescolar, capacitacion, propedeutica ]
    // Si hay mas semestres se pueden agregar aquí
  }
  
  for(const control of disabledControls) {
    // Desactivar por defecto el select
    control.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  
    // Activar si esta dentro de la lista de los que se tienen que activar por semestre.
    if (toEnable[selected].includes(control)) {
      control.removeAttribute('disabled') 
    }
  }  
}
```

```html
<select class="controls" id="semestre" name="semestre" onchange="semestre_onChange(this)"> <!-- onchange agregado aquí -->
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione El Semestre -</option>
  <option value="1">Semestre 1</option>
  <option value="2">Semestre 2</option>
  <option value="3">Semestre 3</option>
</select>
    

<select class="controls" id="paraescolar" name="paraescolar" disabled>
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione El Paraescolar -</option>
  <option value="1">Educacion Fisica</option>
  <option value="2">Danza</option>
</select>

<select class="controls" id="capacitacion" name="capacitacion" disabled>
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione La Capacitacion -</option>
  <option value="1">Contabilidad</option>
  <option value="2">Informatica</option>
</select>

<select class="controls" id="propedeutica" name="propedeutica" disabled>
  <option class="controls" value="0" selected="selected">- Selecione El Area Propedeutica -</option>
  <option value="1">Fisico-Matematico</option>
  <option value="2">Economico-Administrativo</option>
</select>
```